# Tcp client to node js server connection refused

Tags: c#, node.js, tcpclient, system.net.sockets

I am trying to connect a system.net tcp client to a node js server. The server is running and can be connected to from elsewhere, but when i try and connect from the system.net socket the connection gets refused.

here is the client code

```
 string server = "127.0.0.1";
            string message = "a simple message";
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient. 
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
                // combination.

                Int32 port = 6969;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                if(client.Connected == true)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("here, sucessful connect");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("here, not connected");
                }

                // Receive the TcpServer.response. 

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ea)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", ea);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("here, failed connection");
            }
            catch (SocketException eaa)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", eaa);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("here, failed connection");
            }
        };
```

here is the server code

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler            for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {

// We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

// Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
    sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');

});

// Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
});

 }).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran the exact code that you have given and it worked for me. Maybe there is something wrong with your setup? Please would you post the error that you get?

Comment: I just ran it from c# console and it worked. I was trying to get it working of an android emulator, the fault must be there. Thank you very much